# How to set theme colors in runtime?

Tags: android, user-interface, mobile

**Goal**: in the Android app, we receive colors from the server. After login user got a concrete color set from JSON, e.g.

```
{
    "color-primary": "#FFFFFF", 
    "color-primary-dark":"#FF0000"
 }
```

It could be any color. On the next screen received colors should be applied on views (like a theme). Colors can affect the background, text color, etc.

**What have been done:** Having a limited set of themes do not solve a problem, because we can receive the random color combination.
The simple solution is to have something like `BaseActivity` or `BaseView` which applies colors on each view that has a special custom attribute. 

**Problem**: How can I do this more conveniently way? Tried to find the solution for a week - no results:( Please, help me

Comment: Not sure, what you are asking but is it something like generate auto color based on suppose let's say the image has a red color base, so it will generate a red palette and apply on views like text color and background color?

Comment: Hi, @Sam . Not at all, I have color sets stored on web. Colors keys are predefined and always the same (`"color-primary"`, `"color-primary-dark"`, `"color-accent"`, etc.), but values are different. And I want to do it like like Android theme does. That means that as soon as I get the color set from JSON, I want my app to use primary color for toolbar, a dark primary color for the system bar, accent color for all buttons in the app, text color for all labels in  the app, etc.

Comment: I think you need an App theme engine. Go through this repos.. https://github.com/afollestad/aesthetic and also https://github.com/garretyoder/Colorful. the main concept is originated from this repo you can also that if you want https://github.com/garretyoder/app-theme-engine

Comment: Once you do this,you have to set that accent color, primary color as per the value you stored in your web. I personally used the App-Theme-engine to set different theme colors, it is discontinued but it works like a charm

Comment: Thank you, @Sam! Despite that these libraries are discontinued they helped me a lot!

Comment: I have forked App-theme-engine.. and modified (some part which I required and was not working) it previously as per API 27 changes. You can use that or fork that if you want. My github link is in my SO profile

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for a way to change the color in the theme I have to tell you can't. it's because themes are immutable. but as you said you can apply the colors in the activity programmatically, and if you want to change the whole app color, as you said, you can use the BaseActivity pattern to do that. I don't know what you would like to change but it could be something like `actionBar?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(0xFFFFFF))`

another way is to store your colors in a database or a singleton class or a global variable (depends on what you need) and every time an activity loads, change it the way you want. you can use an Interface for this and make activities implement your interface

Comment: Hi, @moshen! Thank you for response! Yeah, the poblem is that I have a list of colors and fonts stored on the web and I want to be able to dynamically apply them in the app. It seems that BaseActivity is the only way to implement this. My idea was to do it the same way as you have a limit set of themes and custom attributes with values overriden in each theme. So I can call applyTheme() in onCreate() and the proper color value is set in custom attribute.